# VB.net: Simple query for OLE DB

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have 6 rows and 3 columns.

1. June 02, 2014 | 1st Shift | 10
2. June 02, 2014 | 2nd Shift | 10
3. June 02, 2014 | 3rd Shift | 10
4. June 03, 2014 | 1st Shift | 20
5. June 03, 2014 | 2nd Shift | 20
6. June 03, 2014 | 3rd Shift | 20

How can I query to show:

1. June 02, 2014 | 30
2. June 03, 2014 | 60

1st column is "DATE", 2nd column is "SHIFT", 3rd column is "Total Sales".

So far I only have this code:

```
  cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT SUM(TotalSales) as [Total Sales] FROM FuelDispensed", con)
```

(which of course just adds everything but doesn't filter / specify what to add)

My apologies for a very simple question I just don't know where else to look my English is so bad I find it hard to understand SQL basics alone.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: you need a WHERE clause to restrict the rows to be summed, then use BETWEEN to set the date (?) criteria

Comment: Oh okay so I could use between. I'll try to get some samples. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `GROUP BY` clause

```sql
SELECT [DATE], SUM(TotalSales) AS [Total Sales]
FROM FuelDispensed
GROUP BY [DATE]
```

Every column in the select-list that has no aggregate function applied to it must be listed in the group-by-list.

Typical aggregate function are: `AVG`, `COUNT`, `MAX`, `MIN` and `SUM`. For a full list see: [12.15.1 GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

Read up on the Group By clause in sql server

do apply to your example you would do something like this
assuming the first column, the date column is called TransactionDate

```
SELECT TransactionDate, SUM(TotalSales) as [Total Sales] 
FROM   FuelDispensed
Group By TransactionDate
```